# Move All Of The Websites To Another Server in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

We have about 150 websites on one of our servers. We want to move that websites to another  server with all of their content, databases, DNS, FTP and application pool users etc.

Current OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 Web edition and  the new one will be the same. Most of websites are Dotnetnuke sites. How can we move whole websites with minimum effort?

Our database server is SQL Server 2008 R2 Web Edition and IIS version is IIS 7.5.

Comment: How is your IIS version 7 when 7.5 ships with 2008 R2?

Comment: It's not clear from your question.  Are all of the DBs located on the same server as the websites or a different one?

Comment: Yes all of the DBs are located on the same server as the websites.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, "minimal" in this case still involves some effort.

- Migrating the apps and databases / data should be relatively straightforward. Apps you just redeploy on the new environment(s), and Data / DB's you just export / import. Here is a link to a guide for IIS configuration export and migration:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753268(WS.10).aspx

- DNS is standard to set up
- The primary points of pain will occur when you go to migrate FTP & application pool users.